# Clearing textfield value

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to clear the textfield in html using javscript if the given condition is met. For ex:- if the user types **awesome** in textfield then it should reset the textfield (no blank space nothing).

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="real" onkeypress="blank()" placeholder="tempo"/><br>
<script>
function blank(){
        if(document.getElementById('real').value=="awesome"){
            real.value='';
        }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('real').value='';`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `real` is undefined, so instead of

```
...
real.value = '';
...
```

do this

```
...
document.getElementById('real').value = '';
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use variable `real` to store input element and use `onkeyup` event:

```js
function blank() {
   var real = document.getElementById('real');
   if (real.value == "awesome") {
      real.value = '';
   }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="real" onkeyup="blank()" placeholder="tempo" />
<br>
```

Another good example would be:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var real = document.getElementById('real');
  real.addEventListener('keyup', blank, false);
}, false)

function blank() {
  if (this.value === "awesome") {
    this.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="real" placeholder="tempo" />
<br>
```

Comment: initializing variable ain't an issue i guess because its working even without init.  "onkeyup" event was the real thing that i was missing

Comment: sure! after earning some enough reputation :D

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
real.value=''
```

to

```
document.getElementById('real').value = '';
```

You can't just say "real.value" because javascript doesn't know what "real" is.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<input type="text" id="real" onkeypress="blank()" placeholder="tempo"/><br>
<script>
function blank(){
    var real = document.getElementById('real');
    if(real.value=="awesome"){
        real.value='';
    }
}
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You where facing issue with input event **"onkeypress"** if change the event and use **"onkeyup"**
issue will be resolved.

```html
 <html>
<script>
function blank() {
   var real = document.getElementById('real');
   if (real.value == "awesome") {
      real.value = '';
   }
}
</script>
<input type="text" id="real" onkeyup="blank()" placeholder="tempo"/><br>
</html>
```